# Drupal Twitter Hashtag Search

Tags: drupal, twitter, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a Drupal site with a content type containing a hashtag field.

What'd I'd like to do is create a view that displays a list of recent Twitter messages related to that hasthag. This would be a global hashtag search, not just messages related to a specific user.

I've installed the Twitter module, but it's not clear to me if this is what I need. That seems optimized for interacting with a specific Twitter account, whereas I'm interested in searching public tweets.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

https://drupal.org/project/twitterfield
Types of storable values are selectable through widget settings, and validated on submission. Options are usernames (@drupal), lists (@drupal/core-comitters), hashtags (#drupal), and search queries (drupal modules).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by properly setting up a few dev modules, specifically these:

feeds, >= 7.x-2.0-alpha8+56-dev

feeds_oauth, >= 7.x-1.0-beta3+2-dev

feeds_jsonpath_parser, >= 7.x-1.0-beta2+12-dev

along with a custom app you setup at dev.twitter.com

I've posted a more complete answer at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107615/pulling-hashtags-and-displaying-them-on-site/136136#136136